# How to store google map options in an external file

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm working with Google Maps API v3 and I'd like to store map options in an external JS file and share the map options with other pages that contain a google map. Let's say there are two different pages with their own google map that points different location, and you want those maps to have the same look and feel by setting some control options.

What I tried:

in `a.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #map {width: 500px; height: 500px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="map-options.js"></script>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), MY_MAP_OPTIONS);
        map.setCenter({lat: 40.782821, lng: -73.965596}); //New York
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

There will be some other pages like `b.html`, `c.html`, etc. that point a different location.

in `map-options.js`

```
var MY_MAP_OPTIONS = {
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    }
};
```

Obviously, these codes wouldn't work. The problem is `position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP` in `map-options.js`; the browser doesn't know what that is because the Google Maps library hasn't loaded yet at the time `map-options.js` was loaded.

Any idea to solve this problem? Or, is there any other way to share the map options with other pages avoiding writing identical codes in many pages?

Comment: try http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

Comment: So you want one map for different pages or different map for different pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the order of loading your scripts and calling initMap function on load of body instead of on load of google map library.

This way both google map library and your external js will be loaded before initMap() is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #map {width: 500px; height: 500px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="initMap()">
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
<script src="map-options.js"></script>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), MY_MAP_OPTIONS);
        map.setCenter({lat: 40.782821, lng: -73.965596}); //New York
    }
</script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```